# Continuum extension v.s. finite sum of the form $\sum n_i x_i$

Tags: set-theory

The continuum hypothesis says that any two uncountable subsets of the (positive) real numbers have the same cardinality.

Suppose we restrict those sets to have property: Any finite sum of the form $\sum n_i x_i$ with $n_i$ an natural number and $x_i$ in the set is written uniquely up to commutativity.

Question: Must all those sets have the same cardinality?

Attempt: I tried mapping the countable ordinal numbers into the positive real numbers, the mapping was very similar to the property stated above. I suspect that the question may be the same as the continuum hypothesis, but the additional condition might make it a more tractable problem.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for the mathematical formulas in your MSE questions. It doesn't take long to learn the basics and it makes your questions much easier to read.

Comment: If you replace $\Bbb{R}$ with a Hamel basis $H$ for $\Bbb{R}$ you get an uncountable subset of $\Bbb{R}$ any of whose subsets $Y$ automatically has your property $B$. So I don't see how your proposal can make  CH more tractable, since $H$ and $\Bbb{R}$ are equipollent (subject to AC)